# Login to static website using Facebook account

Tags: javascript, facebook

My goal is to have a static website with authentication and authorization to my website's content.

1. I wish to use Facebook accounts as login for my users and "wish" not to host anything (e.g. a database table for the users)
2. After login and the user gives permission to my app (app registered at facebook.com) to access his/her basic information, I wish to use that information to check with a static .json file as the authentication process.

Is it possible to do 1, 2? I meant I don't know much about this kind techniques so I'm not sure what I want is possible or not.

What I have done so far is registering a new app at facebook.com and already own an appId.

I'm trying to test it with this coding on my local web server.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Facebook</title>
</head>

<body>

    <div id="fb-root"></div>
    <script>
      window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
        FB.init({
          appId      : 'appId',
          status     : true,
          xfbml      : true
        });
      };

      (function(d, s, id){
         var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
         if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
         js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
         js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
         fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
       }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

I really don't understand what to do next so please guide me a outline steps, or any example coding would be really appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Javascript is run on a browser level, which means that even if you would do that, then anybody would be able to bypass that in a few seconds.

What you want to do is at least to have a script (ie, in PHP) that checks the login from facebook, and then outputs the correct content to the user.

So you CAN use facebook as only mean to authenticate a user, but as to achieve authorization to view content, i'd strongly avoid a static website.